# Embarcadero findwindow Chrome

Tags: delphi, copy-paste, findwindow

I want to copy some selected text from Chrome screen by clicking on a button on a Delphi program. I know I can do it with a code like this but I can't do it for Chrome cause I can't find the name for Chrome. Can anyone tell me how to do that on Chrome as I preselect some parts of text on Chrome?
The code I ty is this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
NpWnd, NpEdit: HWnd;

begin
Memo1.Clear;
NpWnd := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
if NpWnd <> 0 then
begin
  NpEdit := FindWindowEx(NpWnd, 0, 'Edit', nil);
  if NpEdit <> 0 then
  begin
  SendMessage(NpEdit, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
  Memo1.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
end;
end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance
Ali Murat

Comment: This approach will not work for Chrome, because Chrome's rendering window isn't a Win32 EDIT control.

Comment: Also, you can't use `FindWindow()` with windows that have variable captions. You will have to use `EnumWindows()` instead, using `GetWindowText()` inside the callback to look for captions that use text patterns you are interested in.

Comment: To discover windows, you could use Microsoft Spy++ Tool. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2019

Comment: @fpiette Discovering windows won't help, because it isn't a window that has the text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the OP had used the tool he could have - at least - set a better title for his question. This is the tool to use for anyone willing to tinker with FindWindow and EnumWindow.

Comment: @fpiette Over the years, I've learnt to look beyond the question asked, in case it is based on any misconceptions.

Comment: Try using the DevTools protocol to get that information: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/